# How to order random and evenly

Tags: ruby

I have the following array:

```
[1,1,3,3,3,3,1023,1023,1,3,3,3, ...]
```

Is there a way to sort the array in a way where the items can appear more mixed up?
Like:

```
[1, 3, 1023, 3, 1, 3, 1023, ...]
```

Comment: Your output is misleading. Do you want just reorder array? Or to group elements without duplicates?

Comment: what does `evenly` mean? Please be more precise

Comment: As you are dealing with arrays the first place to look for a suitable method is in the class [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html). Based on my understanding of the question the method [Array#shuffle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) would appear to suit your needs. If, however, you found no suitable method in that class the next place to look would be the module [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html), as `Array` includes `Enumerable`, so all the methods in the latter are available for use by arrays.

Comment: Your example doesn't really explain what you want to achieve. It could just as well be some totally random order. I _assume_ that you want to distribute the 4-digit elements (somehow) evenly along the 1-digit elements. But that's just a guess. Please explain what you are trying to do. "random and evenly" / "more mixed up" is very vague and subjective. Maybe also give some more examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could `shuffle`

```
a=[1,1,3,3,3,3,1023,1023,1,3,3,3]
p a.shuffle
```

Output

```
[1023, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1023, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```